# filter values from an array of strings from another array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to get only those strings which are not present in array of objects

```
var objects = [{name:'a',is:false},{name:'b',is:false},{name:'c',is:false}];
var strings = ['a','b','z','x'];

let result = strings.filter(o1 => !objects.includes(o2=> o2.name === o1));
console.log(result)
```

so the result should be only 'z' and 'x'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `objects` array, you can create [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (`lookup`) which has keys as the `name` property and values as the negated version of the `is` property.

```
Map {
  'a': true,
  'b': true,
  'c': true
}
```

You can then use this to lookup to filter your array of strings. If the Map has a value which is `true` then you can remove it from your array (by returning false), otherwise, if the Map doesn't have the current string, you can keep it in the array. Creating a map/object by preprocessing your objects array saves you from needing to use an inner loop inside of your `filter()`, improve the overall efficiency of your code if your array sizes increase.

```js
const objects = [{name:'a',is:false},{name:'b',is:false},{name:'c',is:false}];
const strings = ['a','b','z','x'];

const lookup = new Map(objects.map(({name, is}) => [name, !is])); 
const result = strings.filter(v => !lookup.get(v));
console.log(result);
```

---

Your approach was very close. However, the [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method doesn't accept a callback function like you're providing it with (`.includes()` will search your array for that same function object references your providing it with)

```js
const cb = v => v; // fake callback
const arr = [cb]; // some array contains that callback
console.log(arr.includes(cb)); // providing the callback as a function to includes

// => true, as the `cb` function is inside of `arr`
```

If you want to provide your own "includes" logic, you can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead:

```js
var objects = [{name:'a',is:false},{name:'b',is:false},{name:'c',is:false}];
var strings = ['a','b','z','x'];

let result = strings.filter(o1 => !objects.some(o2 => o2.name === o1));
console.log(result)
```

If you're curious, the above logic with `.some()` has a time complexity of O(N*M), whereas the Map approach has a time complexity of O(N+M), where N is the size of your strings array and M is the size of your objects array.

Answer (score 0):

Used `map` to simplify the array and then used filter and includes to find out the `strings` which are not part of `objects`.

```js
var objects = [{name:'a',is:false},{name:'b',is:false},{name:'c',is:false}];
var strings = ['a','b','z','x'];

let names = objects.map(dataItem => dataItem.name)
let filteredNames = strings.filter(stringItem => !names.includes(stringItem))
console.log(filteredNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/includes) now allow callback function.

instead of this use find:

```js
var objects = [{name:'a',is:false},{name:'b',is:false},{name:'c',is:false}];
var strings = ['a','b','z','x'];

let result = strings.filter(o1 => !objects.find(o2=> o2.name === o1));
console.log(result)
```